# Create object from class in separate file in package

Tags: python

How to correcrly use parent child class in python package? (init file is empty)

```
├── modula
│   │   ├── child.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── parent.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   │       ├── child.cpython-35.pyc
│   │       ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   │       └── parent.cpython-35.pyc
└───└── modulae.py
```

---parent.py---

```
class parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('initialised parent')
```

----child.py---

```
import parent
class child(parent.parent):
    def __init__(self):
        print("initialised child")
```

---modulae.py---

```
import modula
modula.child()
```

Error says:

```
modulae.py", line 5, in <module>
    modula.child()
AttributeError: module 'modula' has no attribute 'child'
```

Comment: Just a hunch but try `from modula import *` instead of `import modula`.

Comment: `modula.child()` you are trying to call the module child. Try this: `modula.child.child()`

Comment: nope, I've already try this without success. As far as I remember I need put something in __init__.py and/or append search paths. I have not use python for a while and completly forget how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

child.py should have `from . import parent` and modulae.py should have `from modula.child import child` or  `from modula import child; child.child()`

Comment: Thanks, looks I'm need refresh my python knowlege

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't import subpackages for you by default. So if you have:

```
modula
    __init__.py
    child.py
```

You cannot access child by doing:

```
import modula
modula.child  # fails
```

Because you only told Python to import `modula`, not `modula.child`. You can get around this in a number of ways.

#### 1. Import `child` in `modula.__init__.py`:

```
# __init__.py
# use a relative import because we're importing from the same package,
# otherwise this could be ambiguous (and doesn't work at all in 
# Python 3).
from . import child

# Now in my script I can do:
import modula
modula.child
```

#### 2. Import `child` in the script (you may want this if you don't want the overhead of always loading `child` when you load `modula`:

```
# Script
import modula.child
modula.child  # works
```

Comment: Thank you for complete explanations